# Join not removing comma from JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to remove the comma appearing like this. I tried Join but it's not working.

[image]

Here is the JavaScript

```
<script>
function shuffle(a) {
    for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
    }
    return a;
}

var arr = [
        '<p><em>"Comment 1"</em> - <strong>Name 1</strong></p>',
        '<p><em>"Comment 2"</em> - <strong>Name 2</strong></p>',
        '<p><em>"Comment 3"</em> - <strong>Name 3</strong></p>',
        '<p><em>"Comment 4"</em> - <strong>Name 4</strong></p>',
        '<p><em>"Comment 5"</em> - <strong>Name 5</strong></p>',
        '<p><em>"Comment 6"</em> - <strong>Name 6</strong></p>'
]

/* note: the javascript that updates the div had to be near the end
 * of the body to work (probably just after the div)
 */
arr.join('');
shuffle(arr);
document.getElementById("randoms").innerHTML = arr.slice(0,3).toString();
</script>
```

And here is the HTML

```
<div id="randoms">
</div>
```

Comment: `join` converts an array to a string, it does not mutate the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.join` does nothing:

```
arr.join('');
```

It creates a string from joining all elements by the empty string, but then the resulting string goes unused. The original array remains an array, so when you call `arr.slice(0, 3).toString()` later, the `toString` inserts commas between the elements.

Change the `toString` to `.join('')`:

```js
function shuffle(a) {
    for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
    }
    return a;
}

var arr = [
        '<p><em>"Comment 1"</em> - <strong>Name 1</strong></p>',
        '<p><em>"Comment 2"</em> - <strong>Name 2</strong></p>',
        '<p><em>"Comment 3"</em> - <strong>Name 3</strong></p>',
        '<p><em>"Comment 4"</em> - <strong>Name 4</strong></p>',
        '<p><em>"Comment 5"</em> - <strong>Name 5</strong></p>',
        '<p><em>"Comment 6"</em> - <strong>Name 6</strong></p>'
]
shuffle(arr);
document.getElementById("randoms").innerHTML = arr.slice(0,3).join('');
```

```html
<div id="randoms">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.join` creates and returns a new string by concatenating all of the elements in an array separated by the string inside it.

Now, you have just called `join` function on assigned `Array().slice().toString()` to `innerHTML`.

`Array.toString()` returns a new string by joining elements with comma.

That should be replaced with `arr.slice(0, 3).join('')`.

```js
function shuffle(a) {
    for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
    }
    return a;
}

var arr = [
        '<p><em>"Comment 1"</em> - <strong>Name 1</strong></p>',
        '<p><em>"Comment 2"</em> - <strong>Name 2</strong></p>',
        '<p><em>"Comment 3"</em> - <strong>Name 3</strong></p>',
        '<p><em>"Comment 4"</em> - <strong>Name 4</strong></p>',
        '<p><em>"Comment 5"</em> - <strong>Name 5</strong></p>',
        '<p><em>"Comment 6"</em> - <strong>Name 6</strong></p>'
]

/* note: the javascript that updates the div had to be near the end
 * of the body to work (probably just after the div)
 */
shuffle(arr);
document.getElementById("randoms").innerHTML = arr.slice(0,3).join('');
```

```html
<div id="randoms">
</div>
```